# How to resize two UI-buttons that are side by side

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I have two UIbuttons that are side by side.
I need to resize the two UIbuttons base on following conditions:

The layout of the 2 UIbuttons :

```
     (1)              (2)
 |-------------------||-|
 | UIButton          ||B|
 |-------------------||-|
```

1) At beginning stage, the UI-button (1) with constraint : right 8 point and left :12 point so that I can place another UI-button 2 on the left of UI-button(1) as shown above.

**Problem:**

I am using a timer for this case. when the time is up.
How to **Programmatically** make the two UIbutton with equal width and a small gap between them such that UIButton(1) width will reduce and UIButton (2) width will increase

These UIbutton will have constraints at the beginning stage.

I can use isHidden for Ui_button(2), but is there a better way not to show it ?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: sorry. Yes, I mean UIButton.

Comment: are you adding the buttons programmatically? @MilkBottle

Answer (score 0):

I think you can play with `EqualWidths` constraint.

**Constraints in storyboard**:

[image]

[image]

**ViewController code**:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button2WidthContstraint:NSLayoutConstraint! // outlet for equal widths constraint for button2.

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button2WidthContstraint.constant = 50 -  self.view.bounds.size.width;
        setUpTimer()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setUpTimer() {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 4, repeats: false) {[weak self] (timer) in
            self?.setButtonWidthEqual()
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }

    func setButtonWidthEqual() {
        button2WidthContstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the Delay.  How can I add the Constraint and What is Equal Width? would appreciate if you can walk me thru the steps. This solution is awesome.

Comment: Unable to follow yr sample. This is what I did. 1) add 2 btns at the bottom as per the above image 2) set constriants on btn1 Left:0, bottom:20, w :320, h:38, btn2 left:8, Right:0, bottom:20, w:15, h:38.  3) select both btn1 and btn2 and set Equal width. This is not working. Can u show your steps?

Comment: @MilkBottle: All the constraints I have assigned are visible in the attached images. First drag and drop both buttons to view and resolve their, left, bottom and right constraints first. For button1, left is 20, that resolves the x-axis position. For y-axis, I have aligned it to center of view but you can give it 20 from bottom. Width is critical, don't hard code it and don't create a constraint for it. Give trailing constraint of 8 points to button2.

Comment: @MilkBottle: For button2, its somewhat similar, right should be 12 points, bottom should be 20 points and its left is already aligned 12 points from button1. Now, you will get errors but dont worry we are going to resolve them by giving an equal widths constriant. Select Button1, then press command and select button 2. Now when both buttons are selected, go to Add new Constraints button at the bottom and assign equal widths. They will be assigned equal widths, which is the state you want them to be after few seconds on app launch.

Comment: @MilkBottle: Follow the code from here, where I have changed the constant on this constraint on viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /*
         Add Button 1 from storyboard and add constraints: (left:0, top: 0)
         Add Button 2 from storyboard and add constraints: (left:10, right 0, width: 44) (Initial width)
         Now made out let of Button_2's width

         The place where u need to make the width of both button same write the following code.
         */

        self.button2Width.constant = (self.view.frame.size.width-10)/2
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { 
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }

        /*
         we reduce 10 from total view width because there is only 10 point space in both buttons & there is no leading trailing space.
         means zero leading trailing space. 
         -> If you specify any leading trailing space then minus that space from total width.
         */
```